# Java 8 - stream convert map's value type

Tags: java

I would like to convert type `List<A>` to `List<B>`. can I do this with java 8 stream method?

```
    Map< String, List<B>> bMap = aMap.entrySet().stream().map( entry -> {
        List<B> BList = new ArrayList<B>();
        List<A> sList = entry.getValue();
        // convert A to B
        return ???; Map( entry.getKey(), BList) need to return
    }).collect(Collectors.toMap(p -> p.getKey(), p -> p.getValue()));
```

I tried with this code, but cannot convert it inside map().

Comment: You need to instantiate a new `Map.Entry`. Try `return new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(entry.getKey(), BList);`

Comment: Syntax error on token ">", invalid Name at SimpleEntry<'>' here

Comment: Solved. My eclipse version is lower to use it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can instantiate `AbstractMap.simpleEntry` in the `map` function and perform the transformation.

E.g. the following code converts `List<Integer>` to `List<String>`:

```
Map<String, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, List<String>> transformedMap = map.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .map(e -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, List<String>>(e.getKey(), e.getValue().stream().map(en -> String.valueOf(en)).collect(Collectors.toList())))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Comment: wouldn't it be possible to avoid using `SimpleEntry` by just doing the conversion in `toMap`?

Answer (score 18):

If I understood it correctly you have a `Map<String, List<A>>` and you want to convert it to a `Map<String, List<B>>`. You can do something like:

```
Map<String, List<B>> result = aMap.entrySet().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        entry -> entry.getKey(),                        // Preserve key
        entry -> entry.getValue().stream()              // Take all values
                     .map(aItem -> mapToBItem(aItem))   // map to B type
                     .collect(Collectors.toList())      // collect as list
        );
```

Answer (score 3):

You may do it like this:

```
public class Sandbox {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, List<A>> aMap = null;
        Map<String, List<B>> bMap = aMap.entrySet().stream().collect(toMap(
                Map.Entry::getKey,
                entry -> entry.getValue().stream()
                        .map(Sandbox::toB)
                        .collect(toList())));
    }

    private static B toB(A a) {
        // add your conversion
        return null;
    }

    class B {}

    class A {}
}
```